# Redux action not being fired inside a callback function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm using react with redux and saga as middleware. Below is a sample generator function that is being fired upon calling regarding action

```js
function* createRoom({ payload }) {
  try {
    // block of code
    }
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error, (errorMessage: any) => {
      console.log(errorMessage);
      createRoomFailure(errorMessage);
    });
  }
}
```

handleError function

```js
const handleError = (error, errorHandler) => {
  if (error.response) {
    const { data, config } = error.response;
    console.log(
      `${data.type} on method ${config.method} at ${config.baseURL}${config.url}`,
    );
    if (data.type === 'Network Error') {
      errorHandler('Network Error');
    } else if (data.status === 400) {
      errorHandler('Bad Request');
    } else if (data.status === 401) {
      errorHandler(
        'Unauthorized user. Please enter valid email and password.',
      );
    } else if (data.status === 403) {
      errorHandler('Access Error');
    } else if (data.status === 404) {
      errorHandler('Method Not Found');
      window.location.href = '/notFound';
    } else if (data.status === 409) {
      errorHandler('Duplicate Value');
    } else {
      errorHandler(data.type);
    }
  }
};

export default handleError;
```

but the problem is in the callback function, I can see the errorMessage in the console when I log it, but when I call the createRoomFailure action, it doesn't get fired.
Here is the createRoomFailure action

```js
export const createRoomFailure = (errorMessage: any) => ({
  type: RoomActionTypes.CREATE_ROOM_FAILURE,
  payload: errorMessage,
});
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: sorry, can't share the full code

Answer (score 2):

Action creators, such as `createRoomFailure` don't do anything by themselves outside of creating the action object. So if you just call the function of  course nothing is going to happen.

What you need to do is to dispatch the action - that way redux can become aware of the returned object from the action creator and process it further.

You can dispatch actions in redux-saga using the [put](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#putaction) effect. But there is still the issue that you can not use effects outside of sagas. So you can't just use `yield put(...)` inside of your callback error handler.

In this case, where it seems your errorHandler is a synchronous function, I would suggest just rewriting it so that it returns the error message as string instead of using callback:

```
const handleError = (error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    const { data, config } = error.response;
    return `${data.type} on method ${config.method} at ${config.baseURL}${config.url}`;
    // ...
  }
};

function* createRoom({ payload }) {
  try {
    // block of code
    }
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = yield call(handleError, error);
    yield put(createRoomFailure(errorMessage));
  }
}
```

In case your `handleError` will need to be asynchronous at some point, you can rewrite it to return a promise, which sagas can wait on.